# Scraping data from tables in a website using R

Tags: css, r, web-scraping

I am trying to learn web-scraping in R and I am trying to scrape data from various tables from the following link [List of Cuisines on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cuisines). At the bottom of the page there are several tables that list different kinds of cuisines I would like to read them separately. I tried using css-selectors but I think I am using them wrong here's my code snippet:

```
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
connection = html_session("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cuisines")
connection %>% html_nodes("table:nth-child(1) a") %>% html_text()
#This lists down all the links in every table there is on that website
#I also tried connection %>% html_nodes("table:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text()
#which gave a different list altogether
```

The output I am trying to generate should be something like

1. Cuisines

   - List of all cuisines
2. African Cuisines

   - List of African Cuisines

and so-on, this list is populated from the HTML tables.

I would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses XPath and gets you all the individual links. I did it this way to show how one can do "loose" child targeting with XPath (you can do a degree with CSS selectors, too). Hopefully it's enough food for thought to do what you're looking to do. Basically you can split this into two steps, one to get the individual tables then the other to get the links under them:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

pg <- html_session("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cuisines")

links <- html_nodes(pg, xpath="//table[contains(@class, 'navbox')]//
                                  table[contains(@class, 'nowraplinks')]//
                                   td[contains(@class, 'navbox-list')]//
                                    li/a")

length(links)
## [1] 1005

head(html_attr(links, "href"), 20)
##  [1] "/wiki/African_cuisine"                 
##  [2] "/wiki/North_African_cuisine"           
##  [3] "/wiki/West_African_cuisine"            
##  [4] "/wiki/List_of_African_cuisines"        
##  [5] "/wiki/Cuisine_of_the_Americas"         
##  [6] "/wiki/North_American_cuisine"          
##  [7] "/wiki/South_American_cuisine"          
##  [8] "/wiki/List_of_cuisines_of_the_Americas"
##  [9] "/wiki/Asian_cuisine"                   
## [10] "/wiki/Central_Asian_cuisine"           
## [11] "/wiki/South_Asian_cuisine"             
## [12] "/wiki/List_of_Asian_cuisines"          
## [13] "/wiki/Balkan_cuisine"                  
## [14] "/wiki/Bengali_cuisine"                 
## [15] "/wiki/Caribbean_cuisine"               
## [16] "/wiki/Caucasian_cuisine"               
## [17] "/wiki/European_cuisine"                
## [18] "/wiki/Central_European_cuisine"        
## [19] "/wiki/Eastern_European_cuisine"        
## [20] "/wiki/List_of_European_cuisines"
```

Comment: I am looking for something like this, it does help. @hrbrmstr XPath certainly seems like a better approach.